# How to share a ruby script which require gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

My question is going to be pretty straight-forward: how can I share a ruby script which requires gems the user might not have installed? I have a simple ruby script which I want to share with a friend to make his job easier. I would like to share it with him as a directory which contains everything needed to run properly without requirim him to install some gems. In fact, he doesn't know about programming, so he should be able to click an executable I already prepared for him and follow the instructions inside the program. Can someone explain how could I achieve this? I'm a ruby student so I would appreciate an explanation. Lots of thanks.

Comment: My advice would first be to bundle your script into a gem, then write a bash script (mac/Linux) or batch file (windows) that runs all the cli commands at the click of a button to handle the install.

Comment: check out [traveling-ruby](https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

The standard answer to this question is:

Define gems in a `Gemfile`, and require the user to run `bundle install` before running your code.

However, it's also possible to take this one step further and define an **inline** gemfile, using `bundler/inline`. For example:

```
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'minitest', require: false # <--- Define your gems here
end

# This is just some sample code to demonstrate using the gems:
require 'minitest/autorun'

class MyTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_should_be_true
    assert_equal true, true
  end
end
```